# React-useForm : No formData are sent on the first request with react-query

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hook-form, react-query

As the title mention, I tried to combine react-query and react-useform.
but somehow, form data that are handled by use-form is empty when i tried to send them via api reques. I know there should be something wrong with my code since the data are perfecty sent on the next form submit.
here is my code :

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState();
const {
  register,
  handleSubmit,
  watch,
  formState: { errors },
} = useForm({
  criteriaMode: 'all',
});
...

const { isFetching, isSuccess, isError, refetch } = useQuery(
    'login',
    () => userApi.login(formData),
    {
        onError: (res) => {
            if (res.response.data) {
                setErrorData(res.response.data.errors);
            }
        },
        onSuccess: (res) => {
            const userReqData = res.data.payload.user;
            setUser(userReqData);
            setErrorData({ errors: {} });
            localStorage.setItem(
                'access_token',
                `Bearer ${res.data.payload.access_token}`
            );
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (userReqData.level === 'admin' || userReqData === 'head_admin') {
                    navigate('/admin');
                } else {
                    navigate('/me');
                }
            }, 2000);
        },
        enabled: false,
        retry: false,
    }
);

...

function handleLogin(data, e) {
  // MAYBE THIS IS THE PROBLEM, formData sould be properly set first , but somehow it doesn't. The 'setFormData' works properly, but the 'formData' state is not updated on the first request(still empty, but not empty on console.log) . Instead, 'formData' is sent on the second request, which is strange.

  setFormData(data);
  refetch();

  // or is there any other way to make refetch send the actual data from the handleLogin parameter right to the useQuery hook?
}

...

return (
  <form
    onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleLogin)}
  >
  ...
  </form>
)
```

'userApi' is an axios request that have been modifided with custom baseurl and headers, so, basicaly it's just a normal axios request.

library that i used :

- react-query : https://react-query.tanstack.com/
- https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `useQuery` to fetch data, not to perform actions.

From the docs:

> A query is a declarative dependency on an asynchronous source of data that is tied to a unique key. A query can be used with any Promise based method (including GET and POST methods) to fetch data from a server. If your method modifies data on the server, we recommend using Mutations instead.

> Unlike queries, mutations are typically used to create/update/delete data or perform server side-effects

[Here](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/mastering-mutations-in-react-query) is a great resource that might help you refactor the code to a mutation.

Comment: i see, i just saw it and theres another simmilar one : useMutation, useMutation is like a request that can only be triggered when mutate() function is calles. thankyou so much